# php valid session redirecting to indexpage

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am create a login page which will redirect to home.php page after login valid.
USING SESSION FOR THIS .

But problem is after login its redirect to index.php page.

But it should redirect to home.php

header.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $valid = $_SESSION['valid'];
    if(!$valid || $valid ==""){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Student Management System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapperMain">
```

index.php

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid'])){
        header("Location:home.php");
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Doctor's BD</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

  <!--Header Area Start-->
<div class="header-custom navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-tg" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="header-logo">

                    <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
                </div>
        </div>


            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
                <form class="login-form-style navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="login.php" id="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="d_email" placeholder="Email address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="d_pass" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
                    <br>

                </form>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>
<!--Header Area End-->

<?php include 'content.php';?>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

home.php

```
<?php include 'header.php';
?>

<?php

    if($_SESSION['valid']=='admin@gmail.com')
        {
            include 'ahome.php';
        }

    else
        {
            include 'dhome.php';
        }
?>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

login.php

```
<!--Login Verification Area Start-->    

    <?php
    include 'config.php';
    $d_email=$_POST['d_email'];
    $d_pass=$_POST['d_pass'];
    $m_d_pass=md5($d_pass);

    $result= mysql_query("select * from doctor_reg where d_email='$d_email' and d_pass='$m_d_pass'",$connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(is_array($row) && !empty($row))
    {
        $validuser = $row['d_email'];
        $_SESSION['valid'] = $validuser;
    }

    else{

        header('Refresh: 5; url=index.php');

        echo "<strong style='color: #3c763d;text-align:center;'><h3>Access denied!</h3>";
        echo "<h4>The user id or password you entered is incorrect</h4></strong>";
    }

    ?>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['valid']))
        {
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
    ?>

<!--Login Verification Area End-->

<!---->


<!---->
```

Comment: What are you setting $_SESSION['valid'] to? Because maybe you should use !isset($valid) in header.php instead of !$valid

Comment: Your login.php doesnt have session_start(); Please check

Comment: Thank you problem solved by adding session_start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, do all session check in a single file `header.php` and include this file in all files.

In `header.php`, modify following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$valid = $_SESSION['valid'];
if(!$valid || $valid ==""){
 header("Location:index.php");
}
else {
 header("Location: home.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: modification done and also added session_start();  on login.php and problem solved thank you